# How to assigning colspan to each td using angular js

Tags: angularjs

I want to assign each `<td>` colspan value based on the percentage.  The below code is not working as expected.

```
<style>
.stacked-chart table {margin:0; padding:0; width:100%;}
.stacked-chart table tr td,.stacked-chart table tr th {border-right:0px solid #ccc; padding:17px 0;}
.stacked-chart table tr th {padding:0; border:1px #fff;}
.stacked-chart table tr td.one {background:#5a5a5a;}
.stacked-chart table tr td.two {background:#959595;}
.stacked-chart table tr td.three{background:#71c5e8;}
.stacked-chart table tr td.four {background:#009fdb;}
.stacked-chart table tr td.five {background:#0568ae;}
.stacked-chart table tr td.fillerspace {}
</style>
    <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div ng-app="myApp"> 
<div class="container" ng-controller="reportCtrl">
    <div class="stacked-chart col-md-8">
    <table ng-repeat="sec in sections" id="chart-section{{$index}}" >
        <thead>
        <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th> <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="quest in sec.questions" ng-if="quest.questtype=='RD'" id="question{{$index}}" >
            <td class="left-rail" colspan="20">{{quest.question}}</td>
            <td class="one"></td>
            <td class="three"></td>
            <td class="five"></td>
            <td class="fillerspace"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td class="fillerspace" colspan="121"></td></tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
<script>
var myapp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myapp.controller('reportCtrl', function($scope, $http, $location, $timeout) {
  $http.get('/apps/bcagencyportal/flatfilejson/testjson.js').success(function(result) {
    $scope.evaldetails = result.evaldetails;
    $scope.sections = result.sections;
    $scope.questions = result.questions;
    $scope.responses = result.responses;
     for (var sectioncount = 0; sectioncount < $scope.sections.length; sectioncount++) {
      for (var questioncount = 0; questioncount < $scope.sections[sectioncount].questions.length; questioncount++) {
        if ($scope.sections[sectioncount].questions[questioncount].questtype == "RD") {
          var countofone = 0,
            countoftwo = 0,
            countofthree = 0,
            countoffour = 0,
            countoffive = 0,
            countofna = 0;
          for (var responsecount = 0; responsecount < $scope.sections[sectioncount].questions[questioncount].responses.length; responsecount++) {
            //console.log("value of Section:"+sectioncount+" Question:"+questioncount+" Response:"+responsecount+" is --- "+$scope.sections[sectioncount].questions[questioncount].responses[responsecount].rating); 
            switch ($scope.sections[sectioncount].questions[questioncount].responses[responsecount].rating) {
              case "1":
                countofone++;
                break;
              case "2":
                countoftwo++;
                break;
              case "3":
                countofthree++;
                break;
              case "4":
                countoffour++;
                break;
              case "5":
                countoffive++;
                break;
              case "NA":
              default:
                countofna++;
                break;
            }
          }
          //console.log("Occurance of each is - countofone:"+countofone+" countoftwo:"+countoftwo+" countofthree:"+countofthree+" countoffour:"+countoffour+" countoffive:"+countoffive+" countofna:"+countofna); 
          var noofparticipants = $scope.evaldetails.participants.length;
          console.log(noofparticipants);
          var percentofone, percentoftwo, percentofthree, percentoffour, percentoffive, percentofna;
          percentofone = (countofone / noofparticipants) * 100;
          console.log("percentofone" + percentofone);
          percentoftwo = (countoftwo / noofparticipants) * 100;
          console.log("percentoftwo" + percentoftwo);
          percentofthree = (countofthree / noofparticipants) * 100;
          console.log("percentofthree" + percentofthree);
          percentoffour = (countoffour / noofparticipants) * 100;
          console.log("percentoffour" + percentoffour);
          percentoffive = (countoffive / noofparticipants) * 100;
          console.log("percentoffive" + percentoffive);
          percentofna = (countofna / noofparticipants) * 100;
          console.log("percentofna" + percentofna);



         /*assigning colspan to each td */
          angular.element('table#chart-section'+sectioncount+' tr#question'+questioncount+'td.one').prop('colspan', percentofone+percentoftwo);
          angular.element('table#chart-section'+sectioncount+' tr#question'+questioncount+' td.three').prop('colspan', percentofthree);
          angular.element('table#chart-section'+sectioncount+' tr#question'+questioncount+' td.five').prop('colspan',percentoffour+ percentoffive);
          angular.element('table#chart-section'+sectioncount+' tr#question'+questioncount+' td.fillerspace').prop('colspan', percentofna);
          console.log("******"+'table#chart-section'+sectioncount+' tr#question'+questioncount+' td.one');
          console.log("*****"+'table#chart-section'+sectioncount+' tr#question'+questioncount+' td.three');
          angular.element('table#chart-section0 tr#question0 td.one')

        }
      }
    }

  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: can you please describe?

Comment: Why don't you have an Angular token in your `colspan` attribute? You should not be manipulating the DOM from a controller.